# из базы mysql в json

Tags: php, json

Мой код:

```
<?php

$object = new stdClass();

$object->{'xxx'} = array();

$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die("Connection to MySQL-server failed!");

mysqli_select_db($con, $mysql_db) or die("Selection of database $mysqli_db failed!");

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Invalid Query, " . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $object->{'xxx'} = array($row);

    var_dump($object);
}

echo json_encode($object);
```

Но у меня выводит только вторую запись. Таким способом (без ошибки) раньше выводил весь массив в `json`.

Comment: не понятно какой запрос отправляется к базе

Comment: и почему вы используете сначала mysqli(подключение, выбор базы) расширение а потом mysql(вывод ошибки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я правильно понял? $object->{'xxx'} должен являться массивом строк, полученных из базы? Тогда может так:

```
$object->{'xxx'}[]= array($row);
```

Comment: откуда вы этот синтаксис подобрали чудовищный?  $object->xxx[]

Comment: @strangeqargo Верно!Закрыто.(только array здесь лишнее, т.к. лишние квадратные скобки). А за синтаксис сорри).

Answer (score 2):

кто вас научил так писать код? пожалуйста, дайте ссылку на учебник

```
<?php

$object = new stdClass();

$object->{'xxx'} = array(); // ваш чудовищный вариант,
$object->xxx = array(); // мой вариант
$object->xxx['abc']  = array(); //проверка
```

это не ответ, но пропагандировать такое написание кода - преступление против любой морали, против уважения к человеку

Comment: Я не изучаю пхп(на 3-ем курсе универа сталкивался в последний раз). Просто нужно понять возможности пхп и джэйсон, т.е. способы вывода записей из базы в формат джэйсон. (Личный интерес).